# Loading resource with Java in both IDE & from JAR (from static context)

Tags: java, maven, jar

My folder structure inside `src` is like so:

```
src
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── organization
│   │           └── projectname
│   │               ├── Transformer.java
│   │               └── Utils.java
│   └── resources
│       └── config
└── test
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── organization
    │           └── projectname
    │               └── AppTest.java
    └── resources
        └── file
            └── test.txt
```

and I want to read the `test.txt` file.

I do use Maven & Eclipse, but I'd like the same code to run when I package in JAR (with `mvn package`) and when someone is running inside IDE or by commandline.

My attempt here fails (gets null):

```
    InputStream input =  Scorer.class.getResourceAsStream("file/test.txt");
    System.out.println(input);  // prints null
```

as does this attempt (gets null):

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = classLoader.getResource("file/test.txt");
    System.out.println(url.getFile());  // prints null
```

I'm quite confident the file does exist at that location inside `src/test/resources/file/`, so I'm wondering what else I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: When you package the jar `src/test/...` will be ignored so the file won't be contained in the jar. By default only `src/main/...` will be part of the final artifact.

Comment: Your first attempt should be `Scorer.class.getResourceAsStream("/file/test.txt")` (note the initial slash).  Be aware that URL.getFile() **does not** return a valid file name; it just returns a portion of a URL, with all of its percent-escapes intact.  Do not attempt to convert your URL to a file at all.  Read it as a URL or InputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `test.txt` is in `src/test/resource` it will not be available in the jar file nor when you run the app in your IDE, unless if you're running test units. Here is an [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

I suggest to move it in `src/main/resource`.

Moving into `src/main/resource` will make able your IDE to have the resource available when you run or debug your project.

On the other hand, Maven will be able to copy the resources into the jar when you run the `mvn package` goal.

To be sure that `mvn package` goal copy the files into the Jar just add these lines into your pom project:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
           <include>**.txt</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Have a look at [Maven Resource Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html) to understand how to write the `<resource>` configuration.

And pay attention to this: if you update your maven pom.xml file, adding one or more `<resource>` part this does not mean that conversely your IDE update the project with this behaviour/configuration (i.e. copy the resources).

So each time you have to check both Maven pom.xml and the IDE project configuration.